# Is there a way to access objects in another file?

Tags: c++

I have written a class inside a file called MyClass.h and it's member functions are located inside a file called MyClass.cpp. 
 How would I (if possible) access the objects created inside that .cpp file from outside that file? 
*MyClass.cpp*
`MyClass* player[] = { nullptr, nullptr}; //The player objects are created using a for loop.` 
    `for (i = 0; i < MyClass::createPlayers; ++i)
        player[i] = new MyClass;`

*main.cpp*

player[i]->getName(); //error: "identifier is undefined"`

*MyClass.h* 
     `class MyClass
    {
    public:
        MyClass();  //constructor
        ~MyClass();   //destructor
        string getName() { return name; };      //returns the name
    private:
        string name;    //the players' name
    };`

Comment: You just need to link it in to the file you want to use it with. What OS/compiler are you using?

Comment: `getName` must be metioned in `class.h` in order for it to be visible in other modules. Update your post with your `class.h` contents. Also, I really hope your class isn't really named `class`.

Comment: @3Dave getName is already mentioned in MyClass.h (see updated code)
I also changed  the name of the class to MyClass (it has another name in reality)